# Should I use an article before words when I refer to them as linguistic units (especially if explicitly using the word 'word' and others)?

Tags: articles, definite-article, nouns

Here are some examples:

> (The) word 'case' can mean different things.
>
> (The) term 'total
> artwork' is a calque of (the) German 'Gesamtkunstwerk.'
>
> (The) letter
> 'U' here needs to be written with two dots, the umlaut.

Comment: Yes, the definite article is required in all these examples.

Comment: @KateBunting thanks!